# How to perfectly fit the text in columns

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am trying to make a table that has text exceeding the header column boundaries and also the first column has extra-long text in it.
`\tiny` make it too small.
what I want the text perfectly to fit for headers and for the text of the first column, I don't mind if it takes extra lines. also I would like to make the data entries vertically centered.

here is what I have tried so far:

```
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
         \hline
          Learning Algorithms & Train=50\% Test=50\% Outlier Removal=No & Train=66\% Test=34\% Outlier Removal = No & Train=50\% Test=50\% Outlier Removal=1428 & Train=66\% Test=34\% Outlier Removal=1428 & Train=50\% Test=50\% Outlier Removal=958 & Train=66\% Test=34\% Outlier Removal=958 \\
          \hline
          Linear Regression Train RMSE & 5616.62 & 5622.72 & 217.92 & 274.63 & 138.74 & 204.55\\
          \hline
          Test RMSE & 7035.95 & 7619.36 & 1134.16 & 252.82 & 57532.62 & 185.13\\
          \hline
          RandomForest Regressor Train RMSE & 4.05 & 4.20 & 10.04 & 10.620 & 2.15 & 6.60\\
          \hline
          Test RMSE & 1860 & 2137.75 & 745.95 & 255.290 & 626.78 & 147.36\\
          \hline
          GradientBoosting Regressor Train RMSE & 429.40 & 448 & 37.17 & 51.54 & 11.83 & 26.53\\
          \hline
          Test RMSE & 2010.69 & 2002.19 & 804.25 & 251.78 & 621.26 & 222.77\\
          \hline

    \end{tabularx}
  
    \caption{Fault Prediction Comparison Table Using Different Algorithms and Train-Test Ratio}

\end{table}
```

new suggestions are highly welcomed.

thank you

[image]

and Here is the same table i had made in Word which is perfectly fine.[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Couldn't you  consider having  a table that uses the full pagewidth? It would be easier to do.

Comment: i am using this table in a report class and it's already spanning the full width of the paragraph. i think reducing font size only and keeping the text to right aligned would work in this case but i don't know how to do that

Comment: You can also enlarge a bit the columns reducing the value of `\tabcolsep`, which is 6pt by default. Setting it to, say, 3pt makes you save 6pt (~2mm) for each column. Other possibility: enlarge locally `\textwidth` with the `adjustwidth` environment (from `changepage`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the following redesign that attempts to avoid lenghty text in the colummn headers by removing repetitions. I also removed most of the lines in order to allow for a more open and inviting look of the table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx,siunitx, caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Fault Prediction Comparison Table using various Algorithms and Train-Test Ratios}
\sisetup{group-digits=false,
         table-format=4.2,
         round-mode=places,
         round-precision=2}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{  X  *{3}{S} 
                   S[table-format=3.2] 
                   S[table-format=5.2] 
                   S[table-format=3.2]  }
 \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{Train:}           & {50\%}   & {66\%} & {50\%}  & {66\%}  & {50\%}   & {66\%} \\
\multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{Test:}            & {50\%}   & {34\%} & {50\%}  & {34\%}  & {50\%}   & {34\%} \\
\multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{Outlier Removal:} & {No}     & {No}   & {1428}  & {1428}  & {958}    & {958}  \\
 \midrule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{Linear Regression}\\ \addlinespace
 Train RMSE                             & 5616.62 & 5622.72 &  217.92 & 274.63  &   138.74 & 204.55 \\
 Test RMSE                              & 7035.95 & 7619.36 & 1134.16 & 252.82  & 57532.62 & 185.13 \\
 \midrule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{RandomForest Regressor}\\ \addlinespace
 Train RMSE                             &  4.05   &    4.20 &   10.04 &  10.620 &     2.15 &   6.60 \\
 Test RMSE                              & 1860    & 2137.75 &  745.95 & 255.290 &   626.78 & 147.36 \\
 \midrule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{GradientBoosting Regressor}\\ \addlinespace
 Train RMSE                             &  429.40 &  448    &   37.17 &  51.54  &    11.83 &  26.53 \\
 Test RMSE                              & 2010.69 & 2002.19 &  804.25 & 251.78  &   621.26 & 222.77 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

Here is a different version of the table using vertical and horizontal lines while still removing repetition from the column headers:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tabularx,siunitx, caption}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Fault Prediction Comparison Table using various Algorithms and Train-Test Ratios}
\sisetup{group-digits=false,
         table-format=4.2,
         round-mode=places,
         round-precision=2}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{ | X|  *{3}{S|} 
                   S[table-format=3.2] |
                   S[table-format=5.2]| 
                   S[table-format=3.2]|  }
 \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{Train:}           & {50\%}   & {66\%} & {50\%}  & {66\%}  & {50\%}   & {66\%} \\
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{Test:}            & {50\%}   & {34\%} & {50\%}  & {34\%}  & {50\%}   & {34\%} \\
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{Outlier Removal:} & {No}     & {No}   & {1428}  & {1428}  & {958}    & {958}  \\
 \hline
\thead[l]{Linear\\ Regression}&&&&&&\\ 
 Train RMSE                             & 5616.62 & 5622.72 &  217.92 & 274.63  &   138.74 & 204.55 \\
 Test RMSE                              & 7035.95 & 7619.36 & 1134.16 & 252.82  & 57532.62 & 185.13 \\
 \hline
\thead[l]{RandomForest\\ Regressor}&&&&&&\\ 
 Train RMSE                             &  4.05   &    4.20 &   10.04 &  10.620 &     2.15 &   6.60 \\
 Test RMSE                              & 1860    & 2137.75 &  745.95 & 255.290 &   626.78 & 147.36 \\
 \hline
\thead[l]{GradientBoosting\\ Regressor}&&&&&&\\ 
 Train RMSE                             &  429.40 &  448    &   37.17 &  51.54  &    11.83 &  26.53 \\
 Test RMSE                              & 2010.69 & 2002.19 &  804.25 & 251.78  &   621.26 & 222.77 \\
 \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for your effort. the redesigning is beautiful however it's making it hard for few readers.
would it be possible to take the text to the second line such as OutLier Removal in the header and RandpfForest Regressor. once they are into the second lines then we can make the first column wider and add the lines coloumn bars

Comment: @awaisumar: What does "add the lines coloumn bars"  refer to?

Comment: i mean adding rows and columns bars to  "---" , "|" to keep the table look cleaner

Comment: also, we can try reducing the font size by merely 0,5 to 1.5 point if needed

Comment: Removing vertical lines and most of the horizontal lines was the entire point of my redesign. Using less lines does not decrease the readability of a table but instead make it look less "caged" and more inviting to take a look at. I have nevertheless updated my answer with a new table containing both horizontal and vertical lines.

Comment: Why do you want to reduce the font size? The table should fit into the available space as it currently is.

Comment: i have just seen your updated effort after commenting, I will consider both designs in my report, and let's see which one is approved by my professor. although both are superb. thank you so much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129159/discussion-between-awais-umar-and-leandriis).

Answer (score 1):

My main suggestion is that you modify the properties of the `X` column type to enable hyphenation of the first word in a table cell and to abandon full justification in favor of ragged-right appearance. Optionally, consider aligning the numbers in the six data columns on their decimal markers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,siunitx,caption}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} % modified 'X' col. type
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X} % modified 'X' col. type
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}} % vertical centering of cells
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C|}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\scriptsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt} % default: 6pt
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\sisetup{group-digits=false,
         table-format=4.2, % default format
         round-mode=places,
         round-precision=2}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{ | L | 
              *{3}{S |} 
                   S[table-format=3.2] |
                   S[table-format=5.2] |
                   S[table-format=3.2] | }
 \hline
 Learning Algorithms & 
 \mC{Train\hspace{1sp}=50\%; Test\hspace{1sp}=50\%; Outlier Removal\hspace{1sp}=No} & 
 \mC{Train\hspace{1sp}=66\%; Test\hspace{1sp}=34\%; Outlier Removal\hspace{1sp}=No} & 
 \mC{Train\hspace{1sp}=50\%; Test\hspace{1sp}=50\%; Outlier Removal\hspace{1sp}=1428} & 
 \mC{Train\hspace{1sp}=66\%; Test\hspace{1sp}=34\%; Outlier Removal\hspace{1sp}=1428} & 
 \mC{Train\hspace{1sp}=50\%; Test\hspace{1sp}=50\%; Outlier Removal\hspace{1sp}=958}  & 
 \mC{Train\hspace{1sp}=66\%; Test\hspace{1sp}=34\%; Outlier Removal\hspace{1sp}=958} \\
 \hline
 Linear Regression Train RMSE          & 5616.62 & 5622.72 &  217.92 & 274.63 &   138.74 & 204.55\\
 \hline
 Test RMSE                             & 7035.95 & 7619.36 & 1134.16 & 252.82 & 57532.62 & 185.13\\
 \hline
 RandomForest Regressor Train RMSE     &    4.05 &    4.20 &   10.04 &  10.620&     2.15 &   6.60\\
 \hline
 Test RMSE                             & 1860    & 2137.75 &  745.95 & 255.290&   626.78 & 147.36\\
 \hline
 GradientBoosting Regressor Train RMSE &  429.40 &  448    &   37.17 &  51.54 &    11.83 &  26.53\\
 \hline
 Test RMSE                             & 2010.69 & 2002.19 &  804.25 & 251.78 &   621.26 & 222.77\\
 \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Fault Prediction Comparison Table using various Algorithms and Train-Test Ratios}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation of the firs example in the @leandriis answer:

- for table is used `tabularray` package
- group of rows are separated by dashed lines

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[skip=1ex,
            font=footnotesize,
            labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Fault Prediction Comparison Table using various Algorithms and Train-Test Ratios}
\label{tab:tblr}
    \small
    \sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4}
\begin{tblr}{colspec ={@{} X[l,m] *{3}{S[table-format=4.2]}
                                       S[table-format=3.2]
                                       S[table-format=5.2]
                                       S[table-format=3.2]
                       @{} },
             }
    \toprule
\SetCell{r} Train:  
        & {{{\qty{50}{\%}}}}  
                    & {{{\qty{66}{\%}}}}
                                & {{{\qty{50}{\%}}}}
                                            & {{{\qty{66}{\%}}}}
                                                        & {{{\qty{50}{\%}}}}
                                                                    & {{{\qty{66}{\%}}}}    \\
\SetCell{r} Test:   
        & {{{\qty{50}{\%}}}}  
                    & {{{\qty{34}{\%}}}}
                                & {{{\qty{50}{\%}}}}
                                            & {{{\qty{34}{\%}}}}
                                                        & {{{\qty{50}{\%}}}}
                                                                    & {{{\qty{34}{\%}}}}    \\
\SetCell{r} Outlier Removal: 
        & {{{No}}}            
                    & {{{No}}}  & 1428      & 1428      & 958       & 958           \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[c=7]{l,font=\bfseries}    Linear Regression:           &   &   &   &   &   \\
Train RMSE          
        & 5616.62   & 5622.72   &  217.92   & 274.63    & 138.74    & 204.55        \\
Test RMSE                             
        & 7035.95   & 7619.36   & 1134.16   & 252.82    & 57532.62  & 185.13        \\
    \hline[dashed]
\SetCell[c=7]{l,font=\bfseries}    Random Forest Regressor:     &   &   &   &   &   \\
Train RMSE     
        & 4.05      & 4.20      & 10.04     & 10.620    & 2.15      & 6.60          \\
Test RMSE                             
        & 1860      & 2137.75   & 745.95    & 255.290   & 626.78    & 147.36        \\
    \hline[dashed]
\SetCell[c=7]{l,font=\bfseries}    Gradient-Boosting Regressor: &   &   &   &   &   \\
Train RMSE 
        &  429.40   &  448      & 37.17     & 51.54     & 11.83     & 26.53         \\
Test RMSE                             
        & 2010.69   & 2002.19   & 804.25    & 251.78    & 621.26    & 222.77        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]